# Transferring all staged files, folder etc. from one branch to another in one go

Tags: git

I know that we can use `git checkout <branch> <file>` to transfer a `file` from `branch` to aother branch but what I like to know is how can I transfer all "staged" (not committed though) files, folder, deleted etc from `branch-two` to `branch-one` in one go?

**Current branch**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/project$ git branch
  branch-one
* branch-two
  develop
```

**current status**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/project$ git status
On branch branch-two
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   dir-one/hello_one.txt
    modified:   file_one.txt
    deleted:    file_seven.txt
    modified:   file_two.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, so I've never done this before, but maybe "git stash" does what you want?  Something like this:

```
git stash save
git checkout <other branch>
git stash apply
```

Comment: Thank you. That will do. The only problem is I have to resolve conflicts.

Comment: yeah... unfortunately you always have a potential for conflicts when porting work from one branch to another.

fwiw I would probably choose a workflow of commit and then rebase or cherrypick onto the desired branch, but I don't see any reason it'd be superior to the stash workflow.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly why git is awesome. Have I been working on the wrong branch for five days? Whoops, no worries, just do a git stash.